# Exception occured while invoking remote Soa service by httpClient

Tags: jar, command, soa

My IDE is IDEA Intellij.
By this IDE i run the program directly and get the right response successfully.
Now i build this program to a jar file by IDEA,
and i run the jar file in windows command line by:

```
java -jar XXX.jar
```

then error occurred in a line which looks like impossible to see error.
eg:in the line which defines a parameter etc.
I don't know exactly what case this error,just the ways of run the program are different.By the way i can't update the source code which i invoke by jar file.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app in IDEA, look for the "Run" tab that opens.

The first line there tells you exactly how Intellij has launch the app (just click on the full line to see if it is truncated with "..." ):

- Java executable used
- (some parameters set by Intellij you don't need to worry about)
- (tons of classpath items you don't need to worry about)
- the main class used
- the program parameters used.

I am pretty sure that if you use these information to build your command line, it will succeed. The main class may be different than the one used by running your app with "java -jar" or some arguments may differ or be missing.